# Random Box Shadow from array of colors

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to assign a random box-shadow to an image (that has a class name of "raven-image-fit") from an array of colors as follows:

```
var colors = ['#fbdc49', '#de5334', '#00ADEE', '#2ca157', '#8f85be', '#97317c'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.getElementsByClassName('raven-image-fit').style.box-shadow = (0px 10px 0px 0px, random_color);
```

... but I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

Any ideas why? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues in your code:

- The `box-shadow` property name contains an invalid character, the `-`, which is used as the subtraction operator. This is the cause of the error you're getting in the console. To work around this limitation, the correct property name is camel-cased: `boxShadow`.
- You need to put quotes around the property value to indicate it's a string literal.
- You need to concatenate the `random_color` value to the string.
- `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements. You need to loop through them all to update their `style` individually.

With those fixed, the code works:

```js
var colors = ['#fbdc49', '#de5334', '#00ADEE', '#2ca157', '#8f85be', '#97317c'];

document.querySelectorAll('.raven-image-fit').forEach(el => {
  let random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  el.style.boxShadow = '0px 10px 0px 0px ' + random_color;
});
```

```css
.raven-image-fit {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="raven-image-fit">Box 1</div>
<div class="raven-image-fit">Box 2</div>
```

Comment: Your code applies the same random color to each instance. How do you make it truly random where each box has its own random color from the array?

Comment: Move the `random_color` assignment inside the loop. I've updated the example for you

Answer (score 0):

```js
var colors = ['#fbdc49', '#de5334', '#00ADEE', '#2ca157', '#8f85be', '#97317c'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.getElementsByClassName('raven-image-fit').style.box-shadow = '0px 10px 0px 0px' + random_color);
```

`box-shadow` needs to be a string I think.

Comment: There's a few other issues too.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are recieving is because

```
document.getElementsByClassName('raven-image-fit').style.box-shadow
```

Is an attempt to subtract `shadow` from your left-hand *value*.

CSS properties have camelCase JavaScript counterpart properties, so you should be targeting the `box-shadow` style as follows:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('raven-image-fit').style.boxShadow
```

To add to that though:

- The value you are assigning to said property should be a string
- `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of matching nodes, not a single one. You either need to iterate through this list, or pluck the item that you'd like. Rudimentary example being:

  ```
  document.getElementsByClassName('raven-image-fit')[0].style.boxShadow
  ```

  Note the square bracket notation I have used here.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('raven-image-fit')[0].style.boxShadow = ('10px 10px 0px 0px' + random_color); seems to work! 
However, how do I apply this to ALL classes of the same name on the page? I have multiple images with the same class, but this only applies the box-shadow to the first one.

Comment: You would need to loop through the list of nodes returned by `getElementsByClassName` (See [Rory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874116/1612146) ). To generate a random colour for each element, simply move your random colour generation into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it with this:

```
var colors = ['#fbdc49', '#de5334', '#00ADEE', '#2ca157', '#8f85be', '#97317c'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.getElementsByClassName('raven-image-fit')[0].style.boxShadow = `0px 10px 0px 0px${random_color}`;
```